# Mysql search and replace when involving "http://"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to search and replace in MYSQL but get an error. I'm quessing it's because of the "http://"

Anyone got any suggestions when trying replace this type of thing?

Code entered:

```
update movies_news set select_page = replace(select_page, ‘http://movie’, ‘http://www.movie’);
```

But it throws the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://movie’, ‘http://www.movie’)' at line 1
```

Comment: `‘` and `’` are not `'`... Bloody smart quotes! Programming languages don't understand them so they think they're syntax errors.

Comment: worked perfect. I'm on a big monitor and it's actually pretty hard to see the difference on a white background.

Comment: Yeah, you have to use a real text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting so it can be accepted:

`update movies_news set select_page = replace(select_page, ‘http://movie’, ‘http://www.movie’);`

contains smart quotes, which are not interpreted as normal single quotes, thus the syntax error. It should instead be

`update movies_news set select_page = replace(select_page, 'http://movie', 'http://www.movie');`

In general, be really careful about copying code to and from 'smart' text editors (Microsoft Word, etc)

Comment: Worth mentioning, don't use word processors like Word (or Wordpad) to write code, use notepad instead; or a proper editor like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)